# draw a text on nose base with face detection API

Tags: android, face-detection, face-recognition, google-vision

I'm trying to draw a text on a face using android face detection API.
Right now, I did this

```
for(Landmark landmark : face.getLandmarks()){
        if(landmark.getType() == Landmark.NOSE_BASE){
            Bitmap moustache = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.moustache);
            canvas.drawText("=====", landmark.getPosition().x, landmark.getPosition().y, mIdPaint);
        }
    }
```

but turns out the text `=====` is draw on top of the head, and I don't know why.
If someone need more code, just let me know

Comment: can you post the result ?

Comment: @Blackbelt http://imgur.com/nuUVDPI

Comment: where are you drawing the other landmarks ?

Comment: Just guessing here, isn't the landmark position relative to the face? From you photo seems like it. Maybe you have to offset this by the face position too.

Comment: @Blackbelt I'm not drawing other landmarks, just this one. the other poins in picture are draw in another method, but I don't care for them

Comment: @Budius mmm, that makes sense...I'll take a look on that

Comment: the getPosition returns absolute positions. Accordingly to the documentation at least

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the point position but I have no idea on how to make it relative to the face...

Comment: I just went to dig on the docs, @Blackbelt is right, https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/face/Landmark#getPosition() it should be relative to the whole thing.

Comment: @Budius that means I should offset the position, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are drawing graphics over a live camera preview, you need to take a few things into account:

1. the device's rotation
2. the scale of the view relative to the size of the preview image
3. whether you are using the front facing camera (which will mirror the image)

The sample code for the face tracker demo has utility methods (translateX, translateY, scaleX, scaleY) to help with this:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/facetracker/FaceGraphic.java#L99

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/facetracker/ui/camera/GraphicOverlay.java#L100